# Apache Drill > sqlline: how to run a sql script containing variable

Tags: apache-drill, sqlline

I am a newbie of Apache Drill, and I need to run a SQL script through sqlline. In most SQL client, it is allowed to use some variables in sqlline, so hereby I would like to ask that is it possible to use variables in sqlline of Apache Drill?

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a [similar question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-user/201512.mbox/%3CCAJ%3D5R7XA0Yr6-oKaiBPNN-UoBUDAAv4j_HWQ0JN-UhG-K%3DUaLw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) on Drill user mailing list. Here is the answer from the same link:

```
You could achieve this by writing a wrapper script:

#!/bin/env bash
VARIABLE="testvalue"

SQL="SELECT '${VARIABLE}' from sys.version;"

sqlline -u jdbc:drill: -n cmatta -p xxxx <<< $SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real world example where I substitute all occurrences of the text 'staticLoadTime' in a drill file with the variable ${staticLoadTime} using sed and then pipe the result to sqlline.  This avoids having to create a wrapper or other temporary file.

`sed 's/staticLoadTime/${staticLoadTime}/g' ${Source}.drill | sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local`